# Difference between img.my_class and .class > my_class

Tags: html, css

What is the difference of the following CSS declarations, and which one is faster?

a)

```
img.my_class{ border: solid; }
```

b)

```
.my_class > img{ border: solid; }
```

Comment: Since they completely different, they cannot be meaningfully compared.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Actually, even though the selectors have quite a different purpose, the selector a) is faster than selector b) for a number of reasons.

Comment: About the question you asked a few minutes ago and was deleted (links around `tr`s) you can try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/72nSG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Is used to get image tag with specific class.

```
<img class="test_class" />
```

b) Is used to get image tag within children of the tag with specific class.

```
<div class="test_class">
    <img />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

a) will select any image with class `myclass`

```
<img src="" class="my_class" />
```

b) will select any image which is direct children of any element with class `.my_class`

```
<div class="my_class">
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

a) applies to all the  with class "my_class"

b) applies to the  which are direct decendents of class ".my_class"

Answer (score 0):

First one is refering to `img` element with `my_class` class:

```
<img src="..." class="my_class" />
```

Whereas second selector is looking for `img` element that is a child (a direct descendant) of other element with `my_class`, e.g.

```
<div class="my_class">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Basically, they both got quite a different purpose, so measuring their speed is quite strange.